# Dependency gives error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inflateSync')

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dependencies, node-modules

I have a Vue/Typescript app that uses an SDK to get data from the backend. This SDK has dependencies that give me an error I cannot solve. I have managed to pinpoint the error to the package: fflate.
(probably also has something to do with webpack)

- Error: Error parsing incoming data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inflateSync')
- build/serve: vue-cli-service
- node v: 14.21.3

Does anyone know how to fix this, or what can cause the problem?

The full error stack:

```
Error parsing incoming data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inflateSync')
    at _callee$ (index.ts:59:24)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63:15)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294:1)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
```

Comment: at a guess `node v: 14.21.3` is quite old now - though, you probably get more than just a single line error with absolutely no reference to where the error is occurring like you've shown here - I take it this error occurs when you try to `build`?

Comment: I have added the full error stack to the description. The error apprears not when building but when making a call with the SDK.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood because you mentioned `build` in the question - yeah, that error is not much help is it ... and this error is in the browser, right?

Comment: Yes, the error is in the browser

Comment: and is that in response to a network request by any chance?

Comment: Yes, the SDK works with web sockets, so this is in response to a call.